# How to measure latency between hosts A and B from a Monitoring host C

Tags: c, node.js, networking, ping, latency

How to measure latency between hosts A and B from a Monitoring/Observer host C?

I have used [Ping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping) module here.

```
var ping = require('ping');

var hosts = ['192.168.1.1', 'google.com', 'yahoo.com'];

hosts.forEach(function (host) {
    ping.promise.probe(host)
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        });
});
```

This results

```
{ host: 'google.com',
  alive: true,
  output: '\r\nPinging google.com [172.217.163.174] with 32 bytes of data:\r\nReply from 172.217.163.174: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=55\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 172.217.163.174:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),\r\nApproximate round trip times in milli-seconds:\r\n    Minimum = 8ms, Maximum = 8ms, Average = 8ms\r\n',
  time: 8,
  min: '8.000',
  max: '8.000',
  avg: '8.000',
  stddev: '0.000',
  numeric_host: '172.217.163.174' }
{ host: 'yahoo.com',
  alive: true,
  output: '\r\nPinging yahoo.com [98.138.219.231] with 32 bytes of data:\r\nReply from 98.138.219.231: bytes=32 time=254ms TTL=44\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 98.138.219.231:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),\r\nApproximate round trip times in milli-seconds:\r\n    Minimum = 254ms, Maximum = 254ms, Average = 254ms\r\n',
  time: 254,
  min: '254.000',
  max: '254.000',
  avg: '254.000',
  stddev: '0.000',
  numeric_host: '98.138.219.231' }
{ host: '192.168.1.1',
  alive: false,
  output: '\r\nPinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:\r\nRequest timed out.\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 192.168.1.1:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),\r\n',
  time: 'unknown',
  min: 'unknown',
  max: 'unknown',
  avg: 'unknown',
  stddev: 'unknown',
  numeric_host: '192.168.1.1' }
```

But I want to pass two IP address and calculate the latency, is there any way to do so?

***If it is possible in any other programing language, then also I would like to know.***

Comment: Not clear what you want. Is it perhaps that you want to calculate latency between 2 remote IP addresses?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Yes, I want to calculate latency between 2 remote IP addresses.

Comment: Good question, I don't think there's an easy way to do this. Also not easy to ask the question in the right way :p.

Comment: You are correct, I don’t have an easy way to do this or ask this.